# Removing stubborn Cisco Content Filter on macOS

Tags: networking, dns, cisco-anyconnect, traffic-filtering

I've had a lot of problems with Cisco AnyConnect Socket Filter causing DNS lookups and other stuff to fail. Sometimes I've even had to reboot the Mac in order for my networking to start again.

My computer is a 2020 M1 MacBook Pro running MacOS Monterey.

After pinpointing the problem to Cisco AnyConnect (which was installed by my employer), I uninstalled everything related to it from my computer. In my Network tab under Settings however, this one content filter from cisco still seems to be running, although I can't find the process anywhere. The only message I get when clikcing it in Network settings is *"Please use "(null)" to control this content filter configuration"*. You can see this in the screenshot below. Even as an admin user, I cannot click the greyed-out minus button.

[image: Cisco AnyConnect Content Filter]

Has anyone come across this or a similar problem before? I'd be happy if someone could help me rid my computer of this stubborn content filter.

Answer (score 5):

The issue is not the VPN but the Cisco socket filtering app which uses the Mac network system extension.
You can Uninstall only the socket filtering app which creates the network adapter extension for dns proxy, content filtering by going to /Applications/Cisco, there you will see the Cisco socket filtering uninstaller option just Uninstall that you can still use the VPN and avoid all dns and content blocking issues